# How can I flash the whole screen?

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I wanted to know how can the the screen flash when I touch the screen. I had tried to `colorizeWhitColor` but it only colorized the background, and I don't know how to return to the same color.

```
scene?.runAction(SKAction.colorizeWithColor(UIColor.blackColor(), colorBlendFactor: 1.0, duration: 0.5))
```

class GameViewController: UIViewController {

```
let viewFlash = UIView.init(frame: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds)

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    if let scene = GameScene(fileNamed:"GameScene") {
        // Configure the view.
        let skView = self.view as! SKView
        skView.showsFPS = false
        skView.showsNodeCount = false

        /* Sprite Kit applies additional optimizations to improve rendering performance */
        skView.ignoresSiblingOrder = true

        /* Set the scale mode to scale to fit the window */
        scene.scaleMode = .AspectFill

        skView.presentScene(scene)

            viewFlash.hidden = true
            self.view.addSubview(viewFlash)
        }
        func flashScreen(color: UIColor, flashTime: NSTimeInterval){
            viewFlash.backgroundColor = color
            viewFlash.hidden = false



   NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(flashTime, target: self, selector:#selector(ViewController.stopFlash), userInfo: nil, repeats: false) //here it tells me that

    }
        func stopFlash(){
            viewFlash.hidden = true
        }

    }



override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {

    /* Called when a touch begins */




    if gameStarted == false {

      flashScreen(UIColor.whiteColor(), 0.1)


        circuloVerde.removeFromParent()
        circuloMorado.removeFromParent()
        circuloRojo.removeFromParent()
        circuloBlanco.removeFromParent()


        enemigoTimer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(0.685, target: self, selector: Selector("enemigos"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)


        gameStarted = true

        circuloPrincipal.runAction(SKAction.scaleTo(0.44, duration: 0.5))

     score = 0

        scoreLabel.text = "\(score)"

        hits = 0

        highscoreLabel.runAction(SKAction.fadeOutWithDuration(0.5))



    }



    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In GameViewController.swift:

```
import UIKit
import SpriteKit

class GameViewController: UIViewController {

    let viewFlash = UIView.init(frame: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds)

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        viewFlash.hidden = true
        self.view.addSubview(viewFlash)

        if let scene = GameScene(fileNamed:"GameScene") {
            // Configure the view.
            let skView = self.view as! SKView
            skView.showsFPS = false
            skView.showsNodeCount = false

            /* Sprite Kit applies additional optimizations to improve rendering performance */
            skView.ignoresSiblingOrder = true

            /* Set the scale mode to scale to fit the window */
            scene.scaleMode = .AspectFill

            skView.presentScene(scene)
        }
    }
    func flashScreen(color: UIColor, flashTime: NSTimeInterval){
        viewFlash.backgroundColor = color
        viewFlash.hidden = false
        NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(flashTime, target: self, selector:#selector(self.stopFlash), userInfo: nil, repeats: false)
    }
    func stopFlash(){
        viewFlash.hidden = true
    }
}
```

In GameScene.swift:

```
import SpriteKit

class GameScene: SKScene {

    override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {

        /* Called when a touch begins */

        if gameStarted == false {

            //This is the new part
            var parentVC = view?.window?.rootViewController as! GameViewController
            parentVC.flashScreen(UIColor.whiteColor(), flashTime: 0.1)
            //This is the new part

            circuloVerde.removeFromParent()
            circuloMorado.removeFromParent()
            circuloRojo.removeFromParent()
            circuloBlanco.removeFromParent()


            enemigoTimer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(0.685, target: self, selector: Selector("enemigos"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)


            gameStarted = true

            circuloPrincipal.runAction(SKAction.scaleTo(0.44, duration: 0.5))

            score = 0

            scoreLabel.text = "\(score)"

            hits = 0

            highscoreLabel.runAction(SKAction.fadeOutWithDuration(0.5))

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: why does it keep talling me: "use of unresolved identifier: viewController"

Comment: @DiegoBenítez Where are you calling it? You have to be on the `UIViewController` with the functions in order for it to work.

Comment: @DiegoBenítez Try to replace the `ViewController` with just `self`. So make the line `NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(flashTime, target: self, selector:#selector(self.stopFlash), userInfo: nil, repeats: false)`. That might work.

Comment: it doesnt, now it tells: GameViewController has no member ¨stopFlash¨

Comment: @DiegoBenítez Okay. I edited my original answer and I think it might work now. It's almost exactly the same as the code you gave, but I moved some of the code around. In your example, the function declarations for `flashScreen()` and `stopFlash()` were _inside_ `viewDidLoad()`. I took them out and moved them underneath `viewDidLoad()`. If that was what was causing your problem, it should work now.

Comment: @DiegoBenítez In what file are you trying to call `flashScreen`? Are you calling it in `GameViewController` or in a different file? If so, can you add that to your answer?

Comment: I added in another file, I would add the code in my question

Comment: @DiegoBenítez Okay I edited my answer again. It is exactly the same as yours now, but I moved some things around. I think you should try copy-and-pasting my code into your project. The only thing wrong with your code is the formatting, so I didn't remove any functions.

Comment: its actually the same, it tells my the same

Comment: @DiegoBenítez are you calling`flashScreen()` from `GameViewController` or `GameScene`?

Comment: from GameScene @skunkmb

Comment: @DiegoBenítez I think I figured it out! I changed `flashScreen(UIColor.whiteColor(), 0.1)` to `var parentVC = view?.window?.rootViewController as! GameViewController; parentVC.flashScreen(UIColor.whiteColor(), flashTime: 0.1)`. You can see it in my answer edit.

Comment: @DiegoBenítez No problem! Good luck with your app!